# Merge local branch to origin develop

Tags: git, github

I have a branch "b2" which i created out of "develop" branch on my local. After making my changes on "b2" i want to write my changes to origin/develop.

```
git push origin develop
```

gave me **Everything up-to-date**

I do not want to push "b2" to origin but only merge my commit on top of develop at origin. What can be the safest way to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have everything committed in your B2 branch.

Switch to develop branch with:

`git checkout develop`

Now pull in the b2 branch:

`git pull --rebase b2`

Once the rebase is completed you can verify everything with:

`git branch --merged develop`

This will list all branches that have been merged into develop.

Now you can push your branch to origin:

`git push origin develop`

Comment: I did that.. now it has created a new problem.. it had added those commits to my existing commits from develop. so i have 2 commits from develop and 2 from b2 and al of them appended to same Pull request...

Comment: let me see if I understand. You had 2 commits on the develop branch and 2 commits on the b2 branch. after the merge you now have 4 commits on the develop branch? That sounds like expected behavior. If you want to undo the changes we just made to the develop branch you can run git reset --hard HEAD^

Comment: perhaps what you had was 2 commits on develop (say blue and green) and 2 commits on b2 (red and yellow) and what you wanted was to push only the red and yellow commits upstream (and not pushing blue and green)?

Comment: yes.. but i pushed the blue/green changes earlier and they were part of a pull request

Comment: git will know not to merge the blue/green changes more than once. This sounds like expected behavior. If you are looking at a git hub pull request it will list all of the commits that have not been applied to git repo you are doing a pull request against.

Comment: from this point forward you should not use the --rebase switch on that branch. Once a branch has been pushed to a remote it should not be re-based again. so you could use `git pull <branch_name>` in the future.

Comment: so is there a way to split the pull request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78918/discussion-between-cryptographic-ice-and-codemonkey).